# Collecting any formalisations of morality

Tags: ethics, kant, philosophy-of-law, formalisation

I'm collecting formalizations of "morality" of any philosophical school.
(My special wishes is anything for Kant, which I don't understand and for whom I didn't find anything seriously formal, at least for my taste. And 'natural law school' from jurisprudence.)

Formalizations = anything with rigorous mathematical structure and what I can calculate, for example, with a computer (in limited toy examples with toy beings/worlds and maybe, *in principle*, for any real word problem). Randomized algorithms counts too.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/computational-ethics-and-a-robots-ability-to-reason-about-morality-from-a-conse).

Answer (score 3):

The mathematical formalisms of [game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory), and, especially, [evolutionary game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_game_theory) and bargaining theory, may be used for the analysis of moral philosophies. An overview is provided in the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/game-ethics/).

A favourite author of mine is [Ken Binmore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Binmore), who has frequent run-ins with Kant's [categorical imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_imperative), which is the central philosophical concept in the latter's moral philosophy.

That may pose a problem for you, since, if a given moral philosophy is game-theoretically inconsistent, then you can't use the game-theoretical formalism for meaningful calculations (if we accept the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion)).

In my tentative opinion that's basically the end of it, but there are some who disagree with the game-theoretical approach in the first place (as addressed in the SEP entry). Perhaps one of them can post another answer, perhaps (or not) defending the claim that [John Rawls' device of the original position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rawls#Original_Position) is an operationalisation of Kant's categorical imperative.

Comment: @zaarcis I just now see that it's you, my quantum friend! Therefore let me mention that there is a developing field of (tentatively called) "Quantum Social Science", the models of which might actually allow for classically inconsistent systems. But I take it that, as things stand, you'll probably have to do the hard work yourself!

Comment: @zaarcis And if you're really interested, check out, e.g., [Quantum Cognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cognition) and, perhaps, work by [Jerome Busemeyer](http://psych.indiana.edu/faculty/jbusemey.php) and/or [Andrei Khrennikov](http://w3.msi.vxu.se/Personer/akhmasda/home.html) for the (rather technical) gist of this field.